# Required Attribute and complex types mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model-binding

I have a type defined as

```
public class Autocomplete
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

I then have a model with this type as

```
public class MPEngagementActivity : IActivity
    {
        [UIHint("Hidden")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [UIHint("Hidden")]
        //TODO: GET THIS FROM THE LOGGED IN USER
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [UIHint("Hidden")]
        public int ActivityType { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Organisation")]
        [Display(Name="Constituency")]
        public Autocomplete Organisation { get; set; }

        [UIHint("ReadOnly")]
        [Display(Name = "MP Office Default Contact")]
        public String DefaultContact { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "MP Contact")]
        public Autocomplete MainContact { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see one of the properties is marked as required, but when testing the model is coming back as valid even though the property was not set in the form, the id is coming back as 0s and the label empty.

How can I get mvc to properly validate this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Autocomplete
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    // This should do the trick with the standard Required attribute
    public static implicit operator string(Autocomplete ac)
    {
        return ac.Label;
    }

    // Optionally, if you want to use a custom required instead, this may be more correct
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Label;
    }
}
```

Then you simply put the `[Required]` attribute on the `Autocomplete` property.

Answer (score -1):

Set the [Required] attribute on the class's properties

```
   public class Autocomplete
    {
        [Requried]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: That would make all the autocomplete properties required.